# I can not upload subfolders inside my folder repository using git push

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to save all changes I make both in the .html files and in the .css and .js files which are inside folders (for a better esthetic)

Let's assume I have in my local repository the following files and folders:

index.html, about.html, contact.html, and the following folders: CSS, js and fonts.  When I type in the terminal `git push origin master` (I have already synchronized my local to my remote repo), the only things that get uploaded/pushed are the .html files, but my CSS, js, and fonts folders doesn't go to my remote repo. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you, buddies.

Comment: Git only tracks content, not empty folders. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIT does not track empty folders. There are multiple approaches to handle this. The easiest is to create an empty file (example name : `.gitkeep`) in each empty directory so they'll be tracked. There are other solutions to this as well. Some of them are listed below.

- https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/bash/how-to-add-automatically-all-empty-folders-in-git-repository
- [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)